# Is html style blocked by gmail for unsigned mail?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, email

I am trying to set up an email verification system as part of a side project web application I am working on. The system uses rails to send email on a linux server via a mailer. I am using my personal email address, which happens to be a gmail address, as a test case. Style information for the HTML email is embedded in a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of the HTML email. This appears to be right, although it's difficult to tell that it's *exactly* correct, since the style data is pretty long. (This same style data works on a web version of the application and I'm embedding it into the email message - I will eventually create a separate stylesheet just for emails, that contains only the relevant styles, but for now, I'm using my web stylesheet for simplicity)

None of the styles appear to be shown in the email as I expect. I noticed that the email that I receive has a little question mark next to the name, indicating that the email is not authenticated with google. The message headers also contain the following:

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 45.56.123.196 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of no-reply@myapplication.io) smtp.mailfrom=no-reply@myapplication.io
```

I'm wondering if the lack of SPF verification is causing google to not show the style data for the HTML version of the email? I can't seem to find another rationale for it. I don't have another email address that doesn't use gmail as a client (both my work and other personal emails utilize gmail), so it's not as though I could test to see if it wasn't routed through google if it would be resolved.

The mailer previews for rails seem to show that the HTML email *should* work, but gmail doesn't show it the same way as the mailer previews (in fact, not even close). I'm not quite sure what I can do to troubleshoot this, so any suggestions on what I can do to help solve this problem are welcome.

Comment: I wouldn't use <style> tags on mails, most mailers don't support it and gmail support is weird. There are tools to write styles in <style> tags and preprocess them as inline style when you send the email. https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails for example

Answer (score 0):

SPF should not be issue for style related issues. You can make sure this by sending email from `gmail` domain (sender domain in SMTP configuration) and your own gmail address. If it works then problem should not be in SPF.

But you would face issue when your email landed in SAPM, in this case external URLs won't work as Gmail will restrict external API calls for security purpose, so if you loaded any image or any other assets then it won't work. That's why images in emails were not opening in SPAM emails.

**Note**: **Gmail will remove whole style in case your style tag has syntax error.** So please make sure you don't have any syntax errors. You have lot of online tools to validate syntax errors.

**FYI**: It's better to solve SPF issues as well, otherwise your email would land in SPAM as most of ESPs are expecting to pass SPF, DKIM and DMARC.